# Question about using two associative algebras irreducible modules to prove the algebras are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

If two associative algebras $A_1$, $A_2$, over some field admit a bijection $f$ between irreducible modules such that dim $M_1$= dim $f(M_1)$ where $M_1$, ($f(M_1)$) are irreducible $A_1$ $(A_2)$-modules respectively,  are $A_1$ and $A_2$ necessarily isomorphic?

For instance, let's say I have an associative algebra $A_1$, where I know it's irreducible modules and that it is finitely generated, and a have a huge list of relations, but I don't know to determine whether some finite subset genenerate's it. I pick a subset, and some relations, and let this subset be the generators with the few relations I chose for an algebra $A_2$. I then notice that $A_1$ and $A_2$ have the bijection of irreducible modules described earlier. Does it follow that $A_2$, with the subset of relations and generators I picked, is actually $A_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be your field. Then the set of (isomorphism classes of) irreducible modules of $A_2=k$ and of $$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}* & * \\ 0 & *\end{pmatrix}$$ both consist of a single irreducible module of dimension $1$. The latter, however, is not even commutative.

Note that $A_2$ embeds into $A_1$, so this answers the second half of your question as well.

Comment: Thanks Dustin! I see that comparing irreducible modules is not enough.  If you don't mind me asking, what if irreducible above in my question was replaced with indecomposable. Do you know of an infinite dimensional counter example still exist?

Comment: $A_1$ has a full flag of indecomposable submodules. The same holds for $\begin{pmatrix}* & * & 0 \\ 0 & * & * \\ 0 & 0 & *\end{pmatrix}$ with the added constraint that the diagonal entries equal each other. I'm not sure why you ask for an infinite dimensional counterexample?

Comment: Scratch that, that's not true. I highly doubt that looking at the dimensions of indecomposable modules is sufficient, but I'll have to get back to you for a counterexample.